# options.disabled == true gives fatal error

Tags: twig

I have a twig macro and I am trying to check if an argument is true or false. Something like this

```
{% macro button(color,content, options = {} %}
    {%  if options.disabled == true %} disabled {% endif %}
{% endmacro button %}
```

But I get a fatal error on that middle line. When I try these:

`{%  if options.disabled is same as(true) %} disabled {% endif %}`

or

`{%  if options.disabled is defined  %} disabled{% endif -%}`

-- it works as expected. Even though the `== true` is documented like that on theTwig website. I really wonder why this is not working.

The error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\RuntimeError: Key "disabled" for array with keys "id, classes" does not exist. in .../button/button-macro.html.twig on line 19 ( ! ) Twig\Error\RuntimeError: Key "disabled" for array with keys "id, classes" does not exist. in ../components/button/button-macro.html.twig on line 19`

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it seems the attribute `disabled` seems to be optional, you'd need to account for this. You can use the filter `default` for this use-case, e.g.

```html
{% if options.disabled|default %}
    disabled
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, if give 'false' as a string argument, it produces true. Is there a filter for that too to avoid that?

Comment: Then use `is same as(true)`